# How can I output XML from code behind in an ASPX file?

Tags: .net, xml, c#-3.0, asx

I need to output XML / ASX on an ASPX page.
The XML is generated from the code behind and will [look like this](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/testing/files/asx.xml).

I'm using string builder to create the XML / ASX.

```
            (...)
            sb.AppendLine("<asx version='3.0'>");
            sb.AppendLine("<title> Spilliste </title>");
            while (i < pdc.Count)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("<entry>");
                sb.AppendLine("<title>" + pdc[i].PageName + "</title>");
                sb.AppendLine("<abstract> Ikke tilgjengelig</abstract>");
                sb.AppendLine("<ref>" + pdc[i].LinkURL + "</ref>");
                sb.AppendLine("</entry>");
                i++;
            }
            sb.AppendLine("</asx>");

            return sb.ToString();
            (...)
```

But how can I output this?

`Response.Write` does not work from code behind. And I'm notable to use `<asp:label>` in the ASPX file, because it needs to be placed within  tags. I basically have a blank ASPX page.

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `Page` for this. Basically `Page`s are for rendering html. If you want to send xml or images or any other type of data for that matter you should use a .ashx file and and a class that implements [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx).

You can see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(VS.100).aspx) on how to implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write should work from code behind:

```
  Response.Write("some test");
  Response.Flush();
```

But you should execute this code in Page_Load method. 
You should prepare separate aspx page for generating xml and redirect user that page. This page should be empty (only `<%@ ... %>` in aspx file).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `IHttpHandler` for this - you can configure which URL's it handles *either* by [making an **.ashx** file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366713.aspx) (very simple) or by [registering them in the **web.config** file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx), which is more flexible, but trickier since the syntax various between classic and integrated mode IIS.

Then, you'll need a simple class with one important member - a ProcessRequest method taking only one parameter - the HttpContext.

Further, avoid using a StringBuilder to build XML.  You can use the safer and more flexible linq to xml classes instead:  Using this type-safe approach also makes it *way* easier to write helper methods to generate parts of the xml tree correctly; and you can query and transform the results to boot.

```
void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    var pdc = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(
        i=>new{PageName="Page"+i,LinkURL="Link"+i});                

    var xmlString = 
    new XElement("asx",
        new XAttribute("version","3.0"),
        new XElement("title","Spilliste"),
        pdc.Select(pdcElem=>
            new XElement("entry",
                new XElement("title",pdcElem.PageName),
                new XElement("abstract","Ikke tilgjengelig"),
                new XElement("ref",pdcElem.LinkURL)
            )
        )
    ).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

    //don't forget to handle headers and set things like content-type too!
    context.Response.Write(xmlString);
}
```

The reason this approach is better than hacking around a .aspx file is that although it's possible in a .aspx file, you'll need to fight the framework to get there - a whole bunch of infrastructure will get in your way, perhaps subtly mangling your output before it reaches the client.  The easiest way to get rid of that is by using a more bare-to-the-metal handler that isn't specifically intended to host aspx controls and generate HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
    string xmlString = "<aaa>sai</aaa>";
    Response.Write(xmlString);
    Response.End();
```