# using web sites to transfer xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, webresponse

How do I setup a scenario where one website hosted at X publishes a URL that when browsed to will return purely XML.

A web page elsewhere is going to hit this URL, load the XML into objects.

So I want a url like http://www.xml.com/document.aspx?id=1

Another site will use webresponse and webrequest objects to get the response from the above page, I want the response to be good XML so I can just use the XML to populate objects.

I did get something working but the response contained all the HTML required to render the page and I actually just want XML as the response.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295892/how-can-i-output-xml-from-code-behind-in-an-aspx-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to this is with a HttpHandler/ASHX file, but if you want to do it with a page it's perfectly possible. The two key points are:

1. Use an empty page. All you want in the markup for your ASPX is the
   <% Page ... %> directive.
2. Set the ContentType of the Response stream
   to XML - `Response.ContentType = "text/xml"`

How you generate the XML itself is up to you, but if the XML represents an object graph, you can use an `XmlSerializer` (from the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace) to write the XML directly to the Response stream for you e.g.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// New up a serialiser, passing in the System.Type we want to serialize
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

// Set the ContentType
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

// Serialise the object to XML and pass it to the Response stream 
// to be returned to the client
serialzer.Serialize(Response.Output, MyObject);
```

If you already have the XML, then once you've set the ContentType, you just need to write it to the Response stream and then end and flush the stream.

```
// Set the ContentType
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

Response.Write(myXmlString);

Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Well I already have the XML I just want to get it as a string the other end, no fanciness just send a string over the internet and it will be xml.  cheers

Comment: i'm afriad i cant see how i use this to send a string

Comment: @RobertHancliff Updated with info on outputting a simple XML string

Comment: No worries I think with your idea i've managed to write something very suitable. Now to consume it. Went with the HTTPHandler idea thanks